# How to replace underscores with spaces in ggplot2 legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The first few lines of my input csv file ("genus_counts.csv") look like below

```
Sample,Woeseia,Candidatus_Nitrosopumilus,Nitrospira,Nitrospina,Pseudahrensia,AqS1,Salinicola,Pir4_lineage,Subgroup_10,BD1-7_clade,Sva0996_marine_group,Anoxybacillus,Others,Unclassified
BW1,1.73959,0.474433,0,1.15973,0,0,3.32103,0,0,0,0,8.69794,27.464423,57.1429
BW2,0.424628,0.679406,0,0,0,0,9.95754,0,0.191083,0,1.18896,0,35.7749522,51.7834
```

and I intend to make a stacked bar chart based on this. I tried the below R code but the names on the legend have still got underscores on them. I introduced the line `pcm %>% rename_all(~gsub("_", " ", .))` so as to replace all underscores with spaces but nothing gets changed on the legend (the underscores remain on the plot!). Any help here would be appreciated.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
pc = read.csv("genus_counts.csv", header = TRUE)
pcm = melt(pc, id = c("Sample"))
pcm$Sample <- factor(pcm$Sample,levels=unique(pcm$Sample))
pcm %>% rename_all(~gsub("_", " ", .))
mx = ggplot(pcm, aes(x = Sample, fill = variable, y = value)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 14, colour = "black", vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1, face= "bold"), 
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"), legend.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"), 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", colour = "black"), 
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12, face = "bold")) + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + 
    labs(x = "", y = "Relative Abundance (%)", fill = "Taxon") + 
    scale_fill_viridis_d(option="plasma")
mx
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rename_all` is used to change the column names of the function. After you `melt` the dataframe the variables are no longer column names but values of `variable` column.

So either you can use `rename_all` before `melt` step or you can replace the values in a `mutate` statement after melting the dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

pcm %>%
  mutate(variable = gsub("_", " ", variable)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sample, fill = variable, y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 14, 
          colour = "black", vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1, face= "bold"), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"), 
          legend.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", colour = "black"), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12, face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  labs(x = "", y = "Relative Abundance (%)", fill = "Taxon") + 
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option="plasma")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response@Ronak Shah; I'm interested in applying 'rename_all' before 'melt' step and I did the below but nothing changes in the output (the underscores are still retained). Don't know if I'm doing something silly here- 'pc = read.csv("transp_Summed_mod_Test_genus_counts.csv", header = TRUE)
pc %>% rename_all(~gsub("_", " ", .))
pcm = melt(pc, id = c("Sample"))
pcm$Sample <- factor(pcm$Sample,levels=unique(pcm$Sample))
mx = ggplot(pcm, aes(x = Sample, fill = variable, y = value)) + .....'

Comment: You need to assign the output back to `pc` after replacing the values. `pc <- pc %>% rename_all(~gsub("_", " ", .))` @RodriguezJMathew

Answer (score 1):

A second option to achieve your desired result would be to pass a function to the `labels` argument of the scale which replaces the underscores with a space, i.e. `labels = ~ gsub("_", " ", .x)`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

pcm <- melt(pc, id = c("Sample"))
pcm$Sample <- factor(pcm$Sample, levels = unique(pcm$Sample))

ggplot(pcm, aes(x = Sample, fill = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 14, colour = "black", vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1, face = "bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"), legend.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", colour = "black"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12, face = "bold")
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Relative Abundance (%)", fill = "Taxon") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "plasma", labels = ~ gsub("_", " ", .x))
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
pc <- structure(list(
  Sample = c("BW1", "BW2"), Woeseia = c(
    1.73959,
    0.424628
  ), Candidatus_Nitrosopumilus = c(0.474433, 0.679406),
  Nitrospira = c(0L, 0L), Nitrospina = c(1.15973, 0), Pseudahrensia = c(
    0L,
    0L
  ), AqS1 = c(0L, 0L), Salinicola = c(3.32103, 9.95754),
  Pir4_lineage = c(0L, 0L), Subgroup_10 = c(0, 0.191083), BD1.7_clade = c(
    0L,
    0L
  ), Sva0996_marine_group = c(0, 1.18896), Anoxybacillus = c(
    8.69794,
    0
  ), Others = c(27.464423, 35.7749522), Unclassified = c(
    57.1429,
    51.7834
  )
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```